# windows 8: How do I check if a tile is a live tile?

Tags: windows-8, desktop, live-tiles

Is there some kind of property that I can check to see if the tile on my desktop is a live tile or not?

On a related note, I wish to add a tile to display photos I have uploaded to flickr.

Comment: Why are you doing this? If it is doing something, then it's a live tile. ;)

Comment: i want to put rearrange my desktop. put all live tiles on one monitor and the static ones on another.

Comment: Okay. Then move all the ones that are moving to one side, and the others to the alternative. Perhaps I am missing your question? Are you trying to do this programatically or through BASH/CMD or something?

Answer (score 0):

The most obvious way of checking that something is a live-tile is if it is flipping and showing things on it.

Another way of checking is to right click the tile and click on the More button. There it should give you two options
1. Turn Live Tile Off
2. Turn Live Tile On

If the option says turn Live Tile On then the live tile is currently off.

These are two methods of doing it, for most tiles looking at them should be enough to see if they are a live-tile or not.